# Movie where the bad guy fools police into shooting at hostages

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller, action

I'm looking for the name of an action/thriller movie where the bad guy performs a bank robbery (or some other heist), then escapes by dressing up hostages as hostage-takers and fooling the police into shooting at them (while he himself pretends to be a hostage). It takes place in a large American (or possibly Canadian) city and I'm pretty sure it's from the '90s. It's similar in tone to other action/thriller movies of that decade.

The bad guy was played by a white, male actor who I believe was relatively famous at the time, but I don't remember seeing him in anything since then.

It's not [Inside Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454848/), where I believe the bank robber also dresses up hostages as hostage-takers or something similar.

Comment: Sounds a *bit* like the beginning of "Demolition Man" with Sylvester Stallone (cop who kills hostages), Wesley Snipes (Bad Guy) and Sandra Bullock (cop in the future).  Though a similar plot (masks) was used in "Batman: Dark Knight" with Heath Ledger as the bad guy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Metro](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119664/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1997)

[image]

> Scott Roper is a wisecracking hostage negotiator. When his friend and
>   fellow police officer is assassinated by a dangerous jewel thief, he
>   is prepared to do just about anything to bring the killer to justice.
>   But as his quiet investigation progresses, he must also train an ultra
>   smart SWAT sniper to become a negotiator just like him.

Here's a link to the [full movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sb7Ca9VbZJc).

The scene you describe begins at at 55:00 and concludes with a hostage mistakenly being shot 6 minutes later. The actor you describe is named [Michael Wincott](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000699/?ref_=tt_cl_t15).

Comment: Yes, that's it! Looking at the description, it certainly ticks all the "'90s action movie" boxes as well! :)